# SweetAlert Confirm Delete

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I have a button for a user to delete a comment that they have left. I am trying to switch the default confirm to SweetAlert but I am having some issues.  When I try to SweetAlert the box pops up but the action is executed before I click 'OK' confirm.  I have looked at some other solutions and haven't been able to get it to work.  Here is the code for the button:

```
<button name="Delete" type="submit" id=' . $note_number . ' class="btn danger-color-dark delete_class btn-block"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
 $(".delete_class").click(function(){

        const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
        }
                if (swal({
      title: "Delete Note Confirmation",
      text: "This action cannot be undone.",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })) {
            // Save it!

            var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var delete_class_for_hide = 'deleteID' + $(this).attr('id');

            $.post("read_notes_inserter.php",{
                del_row: del_id,
                request_number: <?php echo $request_number; ?>
            });
            //$('.'+delete_class_for_hide).hide();
            sleep(2000);
            enter_institution2();
            } else {
            // Do nothing!
            }   
    });
```

Comment: Since function sleep returns a promise,  you need to call a `.then()`.  It would be something like this, `sleep(2000).then(() => { enter_institution2(); });`

Comment: That helps but it still deletes the note even if I click cancel.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if this help, but I think `swal({...})` will return `true` because of this attribute `buttons: true`. So, I suggest follow [this guide](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises). By not putting it in an `if-else statement`.